# Get count from mysql_num_rows result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that collects RSVPs for a party. The person filling out the form (Name) has an option to bring a guest (Guest). In the notification email, I am trying to give an accurate count of RSVPs with total Name and Guest counts.

It is easy to do if I was just getting the Name count (for person filling out the form):

```
mysql_query($query);
$result = mysql_query("select * from tablename"); 
$rowCount = mysql_num_rows($result); 
mysql_close($link);
```

and I would simply use `$rowCount` as the total number of RSVPs. But I also want to include Guests in the count. The Guest is entered as `GuestFirstName` and `GuestLastName` in the form and goes on the same record as the person filling out the form. So I tried this. It worked when I included a guest - it said total RSVPs were 2. But when I did not include a guest on the next test I did, it also counted it as 2. Here is the code I used for that:

```
mysql_query($query);
$result = mysql_query("select * from tablename"); 
$result_guest = mysql_query("select * from tablename WHERE 
GuestFirstName IS NOT NULL); 
$rowCount = mysql_num_rows($result) + mysql_num_rows($result_guest) ; 
mysql_close($link);
```

Like I said, this code yields 2 RSVPs even when no guest is entered. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

cdr6800

and

Comment: So, you want to take the number of Names and Guests?

Comment: One guest per RSPVs right? ?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this in a single query like the following. Also try to use PDO or mysqli_* functions because you use mysql_* which are deprecated.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS total_names,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN GuestFirstName IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS total_guests
FROM tablename;
```

So, if there are 10 invitation rows and only 4 of them have guests results will be:

```
total_names    total_guests
10             4
```

Answer (score 2):

That's an expensive way to get a count of rows: selecting *all* columns from *all* rows in the table, and fetching those from the database to the client, to get just a "count" of the number of rows.

SQL provides aggregate functions. For example `COUNT()` can be used to return a count of rows.

---

As far as why you are getting two rows returned...

```
  WHERE GuestFirstName IS NOT NULL
```

The most likely explanation is that there are two rows in the table which have a non-NULL value assigned to the `GuestFirstName` column. It may be an empty (zero-length string), which isn't considered NULL. Consider

```
  SELECT '' IS NULL       -- 0 (false)
       , '' IS NOT NULL   -- 1 (true)
```

I think you probably also want to exclude from the count rows where the `GuestFirstName` is equal to the empty string.

---

The PHP `mysql_` extension is *deprecated*, and will be removed in future release.  Two suitable replacements are available: **PDO** and **mysqli**.

---

And use a query that returns a single row with a count of rows. That will be more efficient than returning the *entire* table, just to get a count.

And do it in one pass through the data. For a row that includes a Guest, increment the count by 2, otherwise increment the count by 1. Use a `SUM()` aggregate, with an expression that returns either 2 or 1.

For example:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(t.GuestFirstName<>'',2,1)) AS total_including_guests
     , SUM(1) AS count_rsvp
  FROM mytable t
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Guest Name has an empty (but not null) value. Try:

```
$result_guest = mysql_query( select * from tablename 
    WHERE GuestFirstName IS NOT NULL 
    AND GuestFirstName != '');
```

Comment: Pablo...you were exactly right. Your solution worked. Thank you very much.
cdr6800

Comment: The `IS NOT NULL` condition is redundant, and an be removed, since it's not possible for the boolean expression `foo != ''` to return TRUE when foo IS NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this with one query and no additional logic, using `SUM()`

```
SELECT SUM(IF(GuestFirstName IS NULL, 1, 2)) AS totalGuests FROM tablename;
```

This will iterate over all rows and and sum up 1 (if 1 guest in this row is coming) or 2 (if "main" guest + his invite are coming)